# error: the path "nginx-deployment.yaml" does not exist when I use kubectl apply -f nginx-deployment.yaml

Tags: kubectl

I use kubectl apply -f nginx-deployment.yaml  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpCv2.png)

Comment: " kubectl apply -f nginx-deployment.yaml
error: the path "nginx-deployment.yaml" does not exist"

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the full path like C:\YAML\nginx-service.yaml

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If the yaml file will be in .txt format then convert it into filename.yaml("in filename, name it as you like").Copy the content of the yaml text document("which creates the error") and paste the content in notepad++ and save the file as filename.yaml.

Open the cmd, then command
"docker login"
after that, change the directory to yaml file located directory
"cd directory path"

here directory path is(C:\Users\ELCOT\job-portal\job portal\filename.yaml).Don't consider this path,it's an example.Type your system directory path .

After changing the directory,command

"kubectl create -f Filenae.yaml"
it will load for few minutes, then it shows
"Filename.apps/flask-node-deployment created"  .

The above mentioned instructions will works on windows platform ,not in MAC.

Answer (score 0):

Check your path for any typo, sometimes ngnix can be misspelled.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error and this is how I got a solution.

**Background:**

I was learning to apply a basic deployment for nginx and I ran the following command:

`kubectl apply -f nginx-deployment.yaml`

And the same error occurred.

`nginx-deployment.yaml" does not exist`

**Reason:**
It could not find the **nginx-deployment.yaml** file. So, I created one and then it worked.

**Solution:**

1. Created a basic nginx file with the following configuration:

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 name: nginx-deployment
 labels:
spec:
 replicas: 1
 selector:
  matchLabels: 
   app: nginx
 template:
  metadata:
   labels:
    app: nginx
  spec:
   containers:
   - name: nginx
     image: nginx:1.16
     ports:
     - containerPort: 80
```

2. Run the following command in the same directory:

`kubectl apply -f nginx-deployment.yaml`

And **deployment.apps/nginx-deployment created**